# To where may I be repatriated if I don't live where I'm a citizen?

Tags: international-travel, covid-19, emergencies

How do repatriations work for people who don't live in their country of citizenship?

For example: 
I'm a Dutch citizen living in Germany.  The Dutch government contacted me to inform me of an updated travel advise for Germany, but they are not currently repatriating Dutch citizens in Germany (for those living in Germany, it wouldn't make much sense).  I'm not currently travelling and likely won't be any time soon, but what if I were in Spain at the moment, from where both governments *are* repatriating their citizens?

Would Germany allow non-Germans living in Germany to join on German repatriation flights?

Would foreign citizens with residency in Germany need to first get repatriated to their country of citizenship, and then make their own way back to their home in Germany?

Comment: Hi Gerrit, I am interested in how the Dutch government contacted you. Like you, I am Dutch myself and I live in Germany (we're basically neighbours), but I didn't hear anything. Did you receive an email? Did you register specifically for being contacted in these cases?

Comment: @DeltaLima I am registered with [Informatieservice Buitenlandse Zaken](https://informatieservice.nederlandwereldwijd.nl/), they sent me an email "nieuw reisadvies voor Duitsland", they have my email address and other contact details on file.

Comment: Thank you for the link @Gerrit, I  just registered myself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

As far as I can see, after a swift reading of the [KonsG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/konsg/index.html#BJNR023170974BJNE001201310), only 'Germans' and their (possibly non german) families qualify for support. [§ 5 KonsG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/konsg/__5.html)

[§ 6 KonsG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/konsg/__6.html) defines the use of a **Krisenvorsorgeliste**, where only 'Germans' are mentioned.

- i.e. not specifically also german residents

See [the link with information how to create an online account and register](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/service/fragenkatalog-node/14-elefand/606576).

I would suggest trying to register there with your German address and try to also mention that you are a Dutch (thus EU) Citizen.

As an EU Citizen, you have the right to protection from another EU Consulate when your own is not available.

If I remember correctly, one return flight from China to Amsterdam also had 40 German citizens. On arrival the German authorities took over the responsibility for these people. So there may be a pragmatic solution to combine resources in these cases.

---

**Sources**:

- [Wie und wo kann ich mich für die Dauer meiner Reise auf einer **Krisenvorsorgeliste** für Deutsche registrieren lassen? - Auswärtiges Amt](https://www.auswaertiges-amt.de/de/service/fragenkatalog-node/14-elefand/606576)
- [Gesetz über die Konsularbeamten, ihre Aufgaben und Befugnisse - KonsG](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/konsg/index.html#BJNR023170974BJNE001201310)

  - [§ 5 Hilfeleistung an einzelne](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/konsg/__5.html)
  - [§ 6 Hilfe in Katastrophenfällen](https://www.gesetze-im-internet.de/konsg/__6.html)

Comment: I suppose that the "pragmatic solution" is the key here — it is probably organised on a case-by-case basis.

Comment: @gerrit Very likly. The German Embassy in Madagaskar has no consulate, so in such a situation France may take over.